# How to make an index with an optional FK?

Tags: sql, relational-database, hsqldb

##Original question##

So the business model, which I didn't create, have an optional relationship (as in ER model). It's been a while since I've worked DB so I might be forgetting something. Currently the FK (Foreign Key) of the 1st table point to the PK (Primary Key) of the 2nd table, which is an ID ; I don't recall the term but it's the "fake" one, not the "real" one used by the RDBMS (Relational Database Management System). For simplicity, let's imagine there's only 2 tables.

Currently I'm having *nulls in the FK column/attribute* when there's no need for the optional relation. When there is an item in that column, I want the full advantages, checking if there's a matching item at the other side of the relationship, where the FK point to (2nd table), also triggers (although there are currently none) and other validations. I was satisfied up to not long ago when I realized I *didn't want a duplicate* on the important parts of the 1st table, so I wanted to create an unique key but it seems **a key cannot be created which include a column/attribute that might contain null**. So far there's 2 solutions proposed to me although I understand neither.

The 1st was that I'd put defaults, 0 for digit-based types and an empty string ('') for character-based types. What I don't get for that is that the 2nd table already has a row/tuple with a corresponding value (0). If I was to shift the current rows to not have a row with the default, I assume I then would put in the corresponding content a default too, in my case it's a character-based type. So the "cost" of enabling an index would be to make a multitude of *useless joins* then a multitude of useless merges by the software, in my case the database section of an office suite, **Apache OpenOffice Base**. This seem like a lot of added processing and it seem to me some kind of trigger, along with my current design, would be better.

The 2nd was to make a "linked" table (his/her term), a many-to-many relationship but I thought those were only for entries that had more than 1 possible relationship ; that having 0-1 relationship would not use it. And anyway, *I'd still be confronted with the same problem*, where there would not need to have an entry in that "linked" table. IIRC, the 2 "sides" of such table must contain valid candidate keys.

So the 1-1 relationship is already implemented for the cases where the business model do have the need for that option, with the current non-null entries in the FK. Now I just have to implement a method for the cases when the business model do not need the optional part, to allow for a 0-1 relationship, for the *current null entries in the FK while not allowing duplicates*.

##[fredt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471070/) request##
This now contain the **3<sup>rd</sup> example**.

The followind sub-section contain a semi-SQL export from Apache OpenOffice Base using the command `SCRIPT 'PATH\TO\NAME.sql'`. The original file, along with its export, and its non-exported queries, are on [How to make an index with an optional FK? example 3](http://dynv.qc.to/content/how-make-index-optional-fk-example-3).

I'd like a *unique key* on the 3 columns/attributes ID_to_part1, model_number & ID_to_part2 ; however the original question, in the previous section, show HSQLDB version 1.8.0.10 won't allow a null to be contained in a column which is part of a unique key.

###HSQLDB export###
Producing some kind of SQL ; including non-standard statements.

```
SET DATABASE COLLATION "Latin1_General"
CREATE SCHEMA PUBLIC AUTHORIZATION DBA
CREATE CACHED TABLE "Table1"("ID" INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"ID_to_part1" INTEGER NOT NULL,"model_number" VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(3) NOT NULL,"ID_to_part2" INTEGER)
CREATE CACHED TABLE "Table2"("ID" INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"content" VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(1) NOT NULL)
CREATE CACHED TABLE "Table3"("ID" INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"content" VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(1) NOT NULL)
ALTER TABLE "Table1" ADD CONSTRAINT SYS_FK_87 FOREIGN KEY("ID_to_part1") REFERENCES "Table3"("ID") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
ALTER TABLE "Table1" ADD CONSTRAINT SYS_FK_90 FOREIGN KEY("ID_to_part2") REFERENCES "Table2"("ID") ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
ALTER TABLE "Table1" ALTER COLUMN "ID" RESTART WITH 15
ALTER TABLE "Table2" ALTER COLUMN "ID" RESTART WITH 2
ALTER TABLE "Table3" ALTER COLUMN "ID" RESTART WITH 4
CREATE USER SA PASSWORD ""
GRANT DBA TO SA
SET WRITE_DELAY 0 MILLIS
SET SCHEMA PUBLIC
INSERT INTO "Table1" VALUES(0,0,'123',0)
INSERT INTO "Table1" VALUES(1,1,'456',NULL)
INSERT INTO "Table1" VALUES(2,2,'789',0)
INSERT INTO "Table1" VALUES(3,0,'012',1)
INSERT INTO "Table1" VALUES(6,3,'345',NULL)
INSERT INTO "Table1" VALUES(7,1,'678',1)
INSERT INTO "Table1" VALUES(8,0,'123',NULL)
INSERT INTO "Table1" VALUES(9,0,'123',1)
INSERT INTO "Table1" VALUES(10,1,'456',0)
INSERT INTO "Table1" VALUES(11,1,'456',1)
INSERT INTO "Table1" VALUES(12,1,'456',0)
INSERT INTO "Table1" VALUES(13,1,'123',NULL)
INSERT INTO "Table1" VALUES(14,1,'123',0)
INSERT INTO "Table2" VALUES(0,'B')
INSERT INTO "Table2" VALUES(1,'E')
INSERT INTO "Table3" VALUES(0,'A')
INSERT INTO "Table3" VALUES(1,'C')
INSERT INTO "Table3" VALUES(2,'D')
INSERT INTO "Table3" VALUES(3,'F')
```

It seem queries weren't exported, here they are followed by their results

###Query1###
Joined main table:

```
SELECT "Table1"."ID", "Table3"."content" AS "Table3_content", "Table1"."model_number", "Table2"."content" AS "Table2_content"
    FROM "Table1"
        LEFT OUTER JOIN "Table2" ON "Table1"."ID_to_part2" = "Table2"."ID"
        LEFT OUTER JOIN "Table3" ON "Table1"."ID_to_part1" = "Table3"."ID"
    ORDER BY "ID" ASC
```

Result in:

```
ID    Table3_content    model_number    Table2_content
0     A                 123             B
1     C                 456             
2     D                 789             B
3     A                 012             E
6     F                 345             
7     C                 678             E
8     A                 123             
9     A                 123             E
10    C                 456             B
11    C                 456             E
12    C                 456             B
13    C                 123             
14    C                 123             B
```

###Query2###
The rows/tuples which 2 first part of the unique index could "break" the desired unique index should the 3<sup>rd</sup> also match. In other words, other rows aren't a threat (Query1 minus Query2).

```
SELECT *
    FROM "Table1"
    -- It seem HSQLDB won't support tuples as in WHERE (col1, col2) IN ( SELECT col1, col2 FROM
    WHERE "ID_to_part1" IN (
            SELECT "ID_to_part1"
                FROM "Table1"
                GROUP BY "ID_to_part1", "model_number"
                HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
        ) AND "model_number" IN (
            SELECT "model_number"
                FROM "Table1"
                GROUP BY "ID_to_part1", "model_number"
                HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
        )
    ORDER BY "ID_to_part1" ASC, "model_number" ASC, "ID_to_part2" ASC, "ID" ASC
```

Result in:

```
ID    ID_to_part1    model_number    ID_to_part2
8     0              123             
0     0              123             0
9     0              123             1
13    1              123             
14    1              123             0
1     1              456             
10    1              456             0
12    1              456             0
11    1              456             1
```

###Query3###
The rows/tuples which would "break" the desired unique index.

```
SELECT "Table1".*
    FROM "Table1"
        JOIN (
            SELECT "ID_to_part1", "model_number", "ID_to_part2"
                FROM "Table1"
                GROUP BY "ID_to_part1", "model_number", "ID_to_part2"
                HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
        ) AS "non_unique_model"
            ON "Table1"."ID_to_part1"="non_unique_model"."ID_to_part1"
                AND "Table1"."model_number"="non_unique_model"."model_number"
                AND "Table1"."ID_to_part2"="non_unique_model"."ID_to_part2"
    ORDER BY "ID_to_part1" ASC, "model_number" ASC, "ID_to_part2" ASC, "ID" ASC
```

Result in:

```
ID    ID_to_part1    model_number    ID_to_part2
10    1              456             0
12    1              456             0
```

###Beautified important tables schema###

```
CREATE CACHED TABLE "Table1"(
    "ID" INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "ID_to_part1" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "model_number" VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(3) NOT NULL,
    "ID_to_part2" INTEGER
)
CREATE CACHED TABLE "Table2"(
    "ID" INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "content" VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(1) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Please provide a sample set of data for what you are talking about and state which column in which table is referencing the other table.

Comment: @fredt Originally I gave for example in Paul answer comment this: A123B, C456, D789B, A012E, F345, C678E, G901H. The letters, which are leading and **optionally** trailing show the _joined_ content, meaning the row\tuple would have in their corresponding column/attribute content an ID or a null, and of course allowing a join mean that the 2 columns for letters are a FK. So table 1 columns could be: ID, ID_to_part1, model_number, ID_to_part2 ; and table 2 could be: ID, content. The 2nd part of the example (C456) could be: 1, ID_TO_TABLE_NOT_COVERED, 123, null.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the necessary information. Comments are not a substitute for a complete question.

Comment: @fredt I don't feel it should be part of the question. It's simply an example of the 1st solution proposal of my original question (paragraph 3). The question was edited.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO! I find your question a little hard to read.

EDIT:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    data1 INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE table2 (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES table1(id),
    data2 INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

There are records in table1. For each record in table1, there is zero or one corresponding record in table2.

This pattern is similar to table inheritance.

Further explanation:

This would allow you to have to following data.

```
id   data1         id  data2
----------         ---------
 0    1234          0     42
 1    5678          2     57
 2    9012
```

See that the records in table1 with ids 0 and 2 have corresponding records in table2. The record with id 1 does not.

P.S.

Note that you also could combine things into one table. Whether this is advisable depends on your situation.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    data1 INTEGER NOT NULL,
    data2 INTEGER NULL
);
```

Comment: I'm not sure. :| Table 2 is supposed to contain the optional information. So there's an entry in table 1 for every item, of the business model, but there's not always a corresponding entry in table 2. I'm not so good at DB. :\

Comment: table2 ( id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES table1(id) [...] to me that's for options restricted to an item (row) but the option can be assigned to any, or none of table 1 FK.  My case is for a model number, there might be a trailing part or none, ie: A123B, C456. Yes I can assign the _model number_ FK to a default and have the _trailing info_ table corresponding row assign its content with an empty string ; but why bother making the join in the first place? Useless joins seem pretty archaic to me.  @Dan Bracuk This (comment) should answer your question.

Comment: As I understand it (and it is hard to understand), you need to have two tables with a 1 to 0-1 relationship between them. That is the answer I have provided.

Comment: Please see in the OP the 1st solution. I'd rather not have rows filled with defaults, ie: ID 0, name '', etc. for the sole purpose of allowing an index. Having a default-filled, useless, row would take the place of the currently sometimes non-existent relationships ; instead of having a null for FK, there would be a 0, making longer joins ; there's no join when there's a null in a FK column. How do one make an efficient 1 to 0-1 relationship? Let's exchange privately if you still don't understand. I see no PM, give me your email address if we share a http://dynv.qc.to/content/profiles

Comment: There are *no* empty or default rows here. For each record in table1, there will be either zero or one corresponding record in table2.

Comment: How _exactly_ are the non-corresponding record implemented. Mind you I'm referring to my example here. Let me elaborate it: A123B, C456, D789B, A012E, F345, C678E, G901H. Notice some of the leading content (letter) can be repetitive but always present, the tailing content can also be repetitive but can be missing.  What _precisely_ will the FK column, in the model table, contain for instances there's no trailing content?

Comment: Keys work on *columns*. If you want to match on something, you'll need to make it a separate column.

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to create an unique key but it seems a key cannot be created
>   which include a column that might contain null.

My understanding is that you have a FK on which you want to build an index on to enhance performance and that FK may contain nulls (as in @Paul Draper's solution).

I am no expert in HSQLDB, but the [user guide](http://hsqldb.sourceforge.net/doc/guide/guide.html#N102DF), under the Constraints section says:
"*Since version 1.7.2 the behaviour of UNIQUE constraints and indexes with respect to NULL values has changed to conform to SQL standards. A row, in which the value for any of the UNIQUE constraint columns is NULL, can always be added to the table. So multiple rows can contain the same values for the UNIQUE columns if one of the values is NULL.*"

I understand this to mean that you can build an index on the FK in version 1.7.2 of the database even if the column conain rows with the FK value is Null.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure why but it doesn't work where HSQLDB is embedded, in AOO Base. As I have a pretty recent version, the RDBMS should be recent.  It was suggested to not use the embedded version, to link my project to a stand-alone version, but unless it's the only sensible solution, I'll finish this project first then try it out.

Comment: I got the embedded HSQLDB version _1.8.0.10_ from AOO401m5(Build:9714) - Rev. 1524958 2013-09-20 11:40:29 (Fr, 20 Sep 2013) which I got from the call in http://bit.ly/17l2ekx

Comment: The information in the user guide refers to UNIQUE constraints which can have NULL values in the column. PRIMARY KEY constraints do not allow NULL values.

Comment: @fredt, I understand that a PK is different from a Unique Constraint. The OP wants to create A key on the FK, the OP did not mention that the key is a PK. At least this is my understanding of the question. As a result whether the PK allows nulls or not in HSQLDB is not the question here.

Comment: @fredt (and of course Emmad), as seen in the example of Paul's answer (#comment-29129709) there's currently 2 FK in table 1 corresponding to letters in addition to the number and the PK ; the 2nd FK point to table 2 PK. Maybe I'm understanding all of this in reverse but the fact SQL standard allow for null in indexes (unique included), hint that my method isn't so bad. :| But it could because of an entirely different reason. :(

Comment: @DynV, there is only 1 FK.

Comment: The updated question, at fredt request, show directly there's 2 FKs: SYS_FK_87 & SYS_FK_90.

Answer (score 0):

Your question was:

> I didn't want a
>   duplicate on the important parts of the 1st table, so I wanted to
>   create an unique key but it seems a key cannot be created which
>   include a column that might contain null.

You don't want a duplicate on the "important parts" in Table1 but it is not clear which parts must be unique. Assuming the "important parts" are some of these three columns:

```
"ID_to_part1" INTEGER,"model_number" VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(3) NOT NULL,"ID_to_part2" INTEGER
```

A) If you create a unique constraint on "model_number", which is by definition NOT NULL:

```
CONSTRAINT UNIQUE ("model_number")
```

Then model_number values are unique but two different models can have the same ID_to_part1

B) In addition to (A) you can have this constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT UNIQUE ("model_number", "ID_to_part1")
```

Then each model_number will correspond to a unique ID_to_part1. If you don't have NOT NULL on ID_to_part1, then it can contain NULL for those model_number values that do not have an extra part.

C) In addition to (A) you can have this:

```
CONSTRAINT UNIQUE ("model_number", "ID_to_part2")
```

Which has the same effect as (B) but for the ID_to_part2 column.

Your SELECT statement is correct. It shows all models with any optional information they may have.

In short, you can have a UNIQUE constraint on columns that can have NULL in them. But the UNIQUE constraint on model_number is also required.

Edit:

The OP has edited the question again with the requirement that "model_number" is not unique, only the three columns together are unique while some of them can store NULL and the NULL cannot be repeated. This is not possible to achieve with HSQLDB 1.8. In HSQLDB 2.x there is a setting for SET DATABASE SQL UNIQUE NULLS which can be changed to FALSE to allow this. In this case only one UNIQUE constraints on the three columns is needed.

Comment: I haven't forgot the question ; it's updated and there should be a 3rd version within a day.

Comment: The 3rd example show the rows that would break the desired key in Query3. Also notice your answer couldn't satisfy my problem as model_number can't be unique. I had to remove my notice about Table3 to be skipped, it was relevant but I wanted to simplify the explanation. Good thing it was actually in the 1st example. In this new example its show different ID_to_part1 with the model_number 123 ; in addition to the previously shown (example 2) different ID_to_part2.